# update a listview in a fragment in a viewpager from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I understand that this is quite a common issue, and I have referred to many different other questions but I still can't get this to work.

My activity implements a view pager with two tabs and in each tab is a listview. I have a adapter for my view pager which links the two fragments and in each fragment, a adapter to link the data to the listview.

In my activity menu, I have a menu which creates an edittext in an alertdialog for me to input new fields into one of the listview in one of the fragment.

My activity (contains a viewpager)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    subAdapter = new SubAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), data);
    ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager)).setAdapter(subGroupAdapter);
}
```

My viewpager adapter

```
public class SubAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public SubGroupAdapter(FragmentManager fm, data data)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", data);

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
            frag1.setArguments(bundle);
            return frag1;

        case 1:
            Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
            frag2.setArguments(bundle);
            return frag2;
    }

    return null;
}//some other methods below
```

Fragment1 / Fragment2 (both fragments have a listview)

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    frag1Adapter = new frag1Adapter(this, data);
    ((ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView)).setAdapter(frag1Adapter);
}
```

Custom listview adapter for both listviews in both fragments

```
public class ExpenseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
{ ... }
```

As I mentioned earlier, I can input a new entry into either listview from the activity action bar button. However, the listview does not get updated and I can't reference the listview adapter to call notifydatasetchanged() from the activity.

What is the best way I can proceed from here onwards? thank you so much!

I have tried exploring using interfaces, tags but can't get it to work currently.

Comment: see update below which should address your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create a public method for your Fragment1 and Fragment2 like so:

define in your Activity:

`Fragment1 frag1;` 
`Fragment2 frag2;`

then your `ViewPager`:

```
public class SubAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
 {
    public SubGroupAdapter(FragmentManager fm, data data)
   {
      super(fm);
   }

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position)
 {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", data);

    switch (position)
    {
       case 0:
           frag1 = new Fragment1();
           frag1.setArguments(bundle);
           return frag1;

       case 1:
           frag2 = new Fragment2();
           frag2.setArguments(bundle);
           return frag2;
       }

     return null;
     }
}
```

Put this method in Fragment1.java :

```
public void updateFragment1ListView(){
   if(adapter != null){
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

and from your activity call:

```
  if(frag1 != null){
     frag1.updateFragment1ListView();
  }
```

obviously change the names for your adapter if its not called adapter...

Just do the same for Fragment2.java as well

Comment: My fragments are created in a viewpager adapter. How can I further "extend the call" from the viewpager adapter to the activity?

Comment: make your Fragment1 frag1, and Fragment2 frag2 member Variables that just get instantiated in the ViewPager

Comment: I had previously tried this method, turns out that I was not getting the correct fragment reference, and thus unable to call the method from the activity. thanks for the help!

Comment: In any case, I have also passed in the new data that was inserted in the main activity through the method, and then also recreating the adapter and setting it to the listview again. The notifyDataSetChanged() method can be omitted. Hope this helps!

Comment: @user776914 yeah thats a good idea, i just didn't know what data you need to pass so i made the method as simple as possible not knowing a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an interface. Here's an Example:

```
public interface UpdateListFragmentInterface {

    void updateList();
}
```

Then in the Activity, add the delegate as a property:

```
UpdateListFragmentInterface yourDelegate;
```

Wherever you create the Fragment within the Activity, assign the Fragment as the delegate:

```
// Set up and create your fragment.

(if yourFragment instanceof UpdateListFragmentInterface) {

    yourDelegate = yourFragment;
}
```

Then in the Fragment, implement the interface:

```
public class YourListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment implements UpdateListFragmentInterface {

    // Constructors and other methods for the ListFragment up here.

    // Override the interface method
    public void updateList() {

        //Update the list here.
    }
}
```

Then finally, from within your Activity, when you need to update the list, simply call the delegate:

```
yourDelegate.updateList();
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I think you actually need to create a public method in your activity that is something like:

```
public void setUpdateListFragmentDelegate(UpdateListFragmentDelegate delegate) {

    this.delegate = delegate
}
```

Then in the on attach of the List Fragment you will assign it there:

```
if (context instance of YourActivity) {

    ((YourActivity)context.setUpdateListFragmentDelegate(this);
}
```

Comment: A BroadcastIntent and BroadcastReceiver could also do the trick: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X69q01TY1ic